# Sync framework provider for iOS

Tags: ios, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

We're beginning development on an iPhone app that will be using Microsoft Sync Framework to sync between a local SQLite db on the phone to a remote SQL Server 2008 database. Are there any commercial iOS sync providers that work with SQLite? If we can keep from having to write our own that would be great. If not, is there anyone out there who has written one that can give me any advice?

Comment: Did you find anything useful? I'm also considering using ms sync, or alternatively rolling our own sync logic. I'm interested in what you chose and why...

Comment: We're using the MS Sync framework toolkit as a base and have modified it to do what we need.

Answer (score -1):

[Sybase Unwired Platform](http://www.sybase.com/products/mobileenterprise/sybaseunwiredplatform) among the others has the [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and [SQL Anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Anywhere) connection templates, the local database would be `SQLite`, you can try to find more information [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.pubs.docset-SUP-2.1.2/doc/html/title.html), i'm not saying it's easy.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how this applies to my question.

Comment: @Cody C i might misunderstand it, didn't you ask for the existing synchronization solutions for MS SQL and local mobile SQLite ? The SUP is exactly a commercial tool that might be used for that purpose.

Comment: Not exactly. We will be using the MS sync framework toolkit but writing a custom provider for SQLite and was just wondering if there were any commercial or open source providers already written.

Comment: @Cody C Got it now, sorry for the mess then.